# How do I get the bytes sent and recieved in taskmanagers networking tab in cmd

Tags: windows-7, networking, batch-file, cmd.exe

How can I see a NIC's bytes received and bytes sent at the Windows command line?

I've tried the following:

```
netsh interface ip show ipstats
```

and

```
net statistics workstation
```

but they don't show the correct data.

Answer (score 1):

Those statistics come from calling [GetIfTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943(v=vs.85).aspx) from the `IPHLPAPI.DLL`

Copy the demo code from the MSDN link into a new C++ Console Application in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and compile it. Now run the tool.

Comment: I end up with irrelevant information and too many adapters showing (30)